# Running Storm UI

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I use Apache `Storm` from Eclipse Maven Repository. I cannot do `bin\storm ui`. If so, how do I access Storm UI then?

Could not find any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download the binary distribution from https://storm.apache.org/downloads.html instead of maven repository.

Have a look at https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html for more details (for version 1.0.0 -- similar information is available for other versions, too).

Comment: I understand. But is there any way if I have it Maven Repo?

Comment: Theoretically yes. But I don't know how. Why do you want to do this anyway? And why not use the binary distribution?

Comment: Currently I'm using it with binary distribution. Just curious about using it the other way.

Comment: Well. If you dig into bin/storm you will find the command that is issue to start the UI (or use `ps -ef `). Thus, you should be able to run the same command via Eclipse...

Comment: Inside the storm file, able to find the ui() method, and found this : `cppaths = [CLUSTER_CONF_DIR]
    jvmopts = parse_args(confvalue("logviewer.childopts", cppaths)) + [
        "-Dlogfile.name=logviewer.log",
        "-Dlogback.configurationFile=" + STORM_DIR + "/logback/cluster.xml",
    ]
    exec_storm_class(
        "backtype.storm.daemon.logviewer", 
        jvmtype="-server", 
        jvmopts=jvmopts, 
        extrajars=[STORM_DIR, CLUSTER_CONF_DIR])` What is the command that I should try with Eclipse, now?

Comment: You need to figure out the values of the used variables. I guess exe_storm_class will run the Java command using class "backtype.storm.deamon.logviewer". The  rest are options. Everything starting with -D is an JVM option.